# Allowing CheckPoint Endpoint Connect thru SonicWall Pro 240 Firewall

Tags: sonicwall

All,

Having some problems connecting to another VPN (checkpoint) out of our office, which is behind a SonicWall 240.

Other clients (Juniper, Cisco, Cisco AnyConnect) "worked" out of the box.

I am able to connect outside our network (used Android Tether and unplugged wired LAN) on the same machine, with the same set of services (for example windows and other VPN Client services) installed and enabled/disabled.

The failure case behaves as follows: the first time I try to connect, it authenticates, gets an IP, and instantly drops. Subsequent connection attempts yield a message stating that "No VPN connection is needed: The site's resources are already available". However, I have no internal IP on the other network, no access to resources on that network, etc.

I have attempted to setup some rules on our firewall to allow traffic coming from/going to the static external IP address of the server in question, to no avail.

Looking at the SonicWall logs, I see no traffic coming from that server, but I see two 'intrusion prevention' alerts in the SonicWall logs, which I do not understand, as I have rules to allow any service, coming from any LAN, to the Address Object of the VPN Server in question.

First one is: IPS Detection Alert: MULTIMEDIA QQLive -- Client Activity 3, SID: 1312, Priority: Low

Second one is: IPS Detection Alert: PROXY-ACCESS Non-SSL traffic over SSL port -- Traffic Anomaly Detection, SID: 6, Priority: Low

Thanks for reading this far; sorry if this question is painfully basic but I'm in the stereotypical DBA/Network Admin by default position, and have had precious little success googling/playing with firewall rules thus far.